# How can I get the Android SDK, version 1.5, to run on my G1 phone?

Tags: java, android

Well, put it this way. I have already tested an Android application in emulator. Now I want to try that in a real G1 phone. But I am not able to run 1.5 SDK on my G1. Could anyone help me with this, please.

Comment: Not programming related. Please close

Answer (score 2):

Cupcake is available for the G1 Developer Phone.